How to fix the error that occurred in not defining the cuFFT library in Google colab
I am a beginner in CUDA programming and I need to use the cuFFT library for my research in Google colab. But by executing the code, the commands of the cuFFT library are justified with an error.
The compiler doesn't recognize the cuFFT functions.
The Error I received:
The error I am getting is: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/tmpxft_00000272_00000000-11_single_file.o: in function main':
tmpxft_00000272_00000000-6_single_file.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to cufftCreate' /usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_00000272_00000000-6_single_file.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x227): undefined reference to cufftPlan1d'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 

